# 1 out of 1000 boats get hit by lightning each year, if you boat an average amount each year for 20 years what is the probability of getting struck?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Having a discussion with my father over this. We found a article from an insurance company that says 1 out of 1000 boats get struck by lightning each year. He says that the probability of getting struck over a 20 year period is 1/50 but I say it is not. Could someone settle our debate and include the math to back it up?

Comment: Both of you can be right, but also wrong. It depends on how your father justifies the figure, and why you dispute it.

Answer (score 5):

We can assume that your boat getting struck by lightning each year is independent of previous years.

The probability of your boat not getting struck by lightning in a year is $\frac{999}{1000} $, so that the probability of it not getting struck 20 years in a row is
$\left(\frac{999}{1000}\right)^{20} \approx 0.9802 $. Since $1-.9802 = .0198$  there is about 1.98% chance your boat gets struck by lightning in a 20 year period.

Comment: Right, and that's close to the quoted $1/50$, also close to $20 \cdot 1/1000$ because by binomial expansion $\,1 - (1 - 1/1000)^{20} \approx 20 \cdot 1/1000\,$.

Comment: It’s only close because the numbers are so small. For an event that happens with 10% probability or for the number of lightning strikes in 1000 years it’s totally off.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of being hit ever is $$1-\left(1-\frac1{1000}\right)^{20}$$ You’re father’s calculation is close, but it actually counts the average number of times you’ll be hit in $20$ years.

A very few people will be hit more than once, so the average will be slightly higher than the probability.

$$1-\frac1{1000}$$

is the probability that you won’t be hit in a particular year.

$$\left(1-\frac1{1000}\right)^{20}$$

Is  the probability of not being hit ever, over $20$ years.

So $$1-\left(1-\frac1{1000}\right)^{20}$$
is the probability that you will be hit one or more times in the $20$ years.

That said, given how unlikely the actual probability is exactly $1/1000,$ your dad’s answer is good enough.